# jQuery mouseleave remove if next hover id not equal to 'X'

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm trying to detect what the next hover is after an icon is hovered.

When the icon (class="infoToolTip") is hovered a text box is shown, is the user leaves the icon and goes onto the text box (id="tooltip") I need to remain to show the text box.

If the hovered item is neither 'tooltip' or 'infoToolTip' then I need to remove any instance of 'tooltip'. Below is the jquery I so far, any help with this would be great. Thanks in advance for any replies.

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.infoToolTip',  function(){ 
     $('#tooltip').css({ left: pos_left, top: pos_top }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);
});

$('body').on('mouseleave', '#tooltip, .infoToolTip', function(){        
     $('#tooltip').remove();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/E5Uxf/1/)

Comment: a jsFiddle would be nice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/E5Uxf/1/

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the 'is :hover'

```
        $('body').on('mouseleave', '.infoToolTip', function(){      
                if(!$("#tooltip").is(':hover')) {
                $('#tooltip').remove();
                }
        });
```